# Url Rewrite rules and the Piranha Manager interface

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, piranha-cms

Working on my site today I added in some of the usual rewrite rules I use for converting urls to all lower case and also adding a trailing slash to the url should it not have one.

On doing this I could no longer access the Manager interface. The css disappeared for the login page and when logging in to didn't work and redirected me to the home page.

I have added some rewrite rules to work around this but was wondering if there was a better way to be doing it that you have already done?

The rewrite are shown below if you think this is a viable solution and want to use them in a Gist.

Note that the first 2 rules are for stopping processing when accessing the manager interface and the last two are just a couple of out of the box ones from IIS. One final point. I normally have trailing slashes but when working with Piranha had to enforce no trailing spaces to get to the manager interface once logged in.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="IgnorePiranhaAreas" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="areas/manager" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="IgnorePiranhaManager" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/manager" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)/$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RemoveTrailingSkalRulel1 is screwing it up. Just remove it and you're fine.